# Area of quadrilateral $OBMN$ which s inscribe in a $\triangle$

Tags: analytic-geometry

> $\triangle OAB$ has virtices $A(0,12)\;\;,B(5,0)\;\;,O(0,0)$. There exists a line $l$ cutting $AB$ and $OA$ at $M$
>
> and $N$ respectively such that thses circle can be inscribed in $\triangle AMN$ and quadrilateral $OBMN$
>
> also these two circle are tangent to the line $l$ at the same point. If line passess through $(0,-8)\;,$
>
> Then area of quadrilateral $OBMN$ is

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let Equation of line be $y-0 = m(x+8)\Rightarrow y=m(x+8)\;,$ Where $m$ is slope.

Now equation of line $AB$ is $12x+5y=60$

Now how can i solve it, Help required, Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a sketch of it?

Comment: The question is the same as [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1855025/area-of-a-quadrilateral-in-which-a-circle-can-be-inscribed-using-algebraic-geome) except the part "if line $l$ passes through the point $(0,\color{red}{+}8)$". So, are you sure that the point in your question is $(0,\color{red}{-}8)$?